# Approaches for solving P vs NP problem

Tags: np-complete

I want to get acquainted with approaches made to solve P vs NP problem.

1) What is already achieved in solving the P vs NP problem?

2) What articles are most cited/famous in that field? Please, provide links for them.

3) How one can divide existing approaches to different classes?

Comment: This would be better asked on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com.  Also, it is fairly easy to Google something like "P vs. NP survey."

Comment: Posting it to cstheory could result in flaming.

Answer (score 4):

Someone else posted this link in partial reply to another question recently. I think it answers 1 and 2, at least. http://www.win.tue.nl/~gwoegi/P-versus-NP.htm

Comment: It technically answers 2, but I think in a somewhat perverse sense.

Comment: @Willie Wong, I think it also answers 3 in a somewhat perverse sense: we can divide existing approaches into crackpot and non-crackpot, with all but a handful (maybe all but one) of them falling into the crackpot category.

Comment: :D, it is also funny, that nearby half of researchers claim P=NP, nearby half claim opposite.